# postgresql fast transfer of a table between databases

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse, postgresql-9.1, database-optimization

I have a postgresql operational DB with data partitioned per day
and a postgresql data warehouse DB.
In order to copy the data quickly from the operational DB to the DWH I would like to copy the tables as fast and with least of resources used.
Since the tables are partitioned by day, I understand that each partition is a table as itself.
Is that means I can somehow copy the data files between the machines and create the tables in the DWH with those data files?
What is the best practice in that case?

EDIT:
I will answer all questions asked in here:
1. I'm building an ETL. First step of ETL is to copy the data with less influence on the operational DB.
2. I would want to replicate the data if this won't slow the operational DB writings.
3. A bit more data, The operational DB is not in my responsepbility but the main concern is the write time on the that DB.
It writes about 500 Million rows a day where there are hours that are more loaded but there aren't hours with no writings at all.
4. I came across with few tools/ways - Replication, pg_dump. But I couldn't find something that compare the tools to know when to use what and to understand what is fit to my case.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to have the DWH database replicate the operational database in real-time? Perhaps tell more about the frequency and volume of reads from and writes to the operation database, and the requirements/intention of DWH.

Comment: Are you building an ETL process? Or is your "data warehouse" just a copy of the operational system (in which case it should be termed an "operational data store")

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a bulk transfer I would actually consider running pg_dump on the warehouse system and piping the results into psql once a day.  You could probably run Slony too but that woudl require more resources, and would probably be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good ways to replicate data between databases. While just looking for a

> fast transfer of a table between databases

... a simple and fast solution is provided by the extension [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html). There are many examples here on SO. Try a search.

If you want a wider approach, continued synchronization etc. consider one of the established tools for replication. There is nice [comparison in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/different-replication-solutions.html) to get you started.

Comment: I looked at this search. And I found some ways. I wanted to get extra information on what is best to my case.